# cpu usage: is there any events fired when overall system cpu usage changes

Tags: linux, process, cpu

Is there any way to get system cpu usage without polling method? If I do poll, I can get that detail from top, but is that optimal?. Is there any system wide signals that are emitted when there is a cpu usage change?

Comment: there is a whole industry of applications designed for systems monitoring. `top` and `ps -o ...` are your entry points. Not really a programming question. Voting to close. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On `linux` there is no other way to get CPU usage than polling `/proc/stat`. It is probably a question of performance as it would waste a lot of CPU cycles to do more than updating a counter when there is a context switch.

If you want info about a particular process, you can also poll `/proc/[PID]/stat`.